# Python - List comprehension list of tuple list to tuple list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How can I transform, with list comprehension, a list of tuple list to tuple list?

Example:

convert `[[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)], [(7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)]]` to `[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this, using list comprehension:

```
list_ = [[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)], [(7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)]]
flat_list = [item for sublist in list_ for item in sublist]
print(flat_list)
```

Or as a function:

```
def flat_list(list_):
    return [item for sublist in list_ for item in sublist]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(flat_list([[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)], [(7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)]]))
```

Another common way of doing this would be to use the the `itertools` module:

```
def flat_list(list_):
    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(list_))
```

From the linked SO question, you can also see some timings.